# Header modifications do not take effect in fresh build

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am trying to use BRIEF descriptor in OpenCV 3.1 for andoid. In order to achieve that OpenCV has to be built from source with _contrib. So I compiled it without errors and could also see BRIEF.cpp.o beeing built in the command window.

So when I try to use it, my android app crashes throwing

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Specified descriptor extractor type is not supported.) in static cv::javaDescriptorExtractor* cv::javaDescriptorExtractor::create(int), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp, line 374

So I checked features2d_manual.hpp. Line 374 is the default expression of a switch case block:

```
CV_WRAP static javaDescriptorExtractor* create( int extractorType )
{
    //String name;

    if (extractorType > OPPONENTEXTRACTOR)
    {
        //name = "Opponent";
        extractorType -= OPPONENTEXTRACTOR;
    }

    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> de;
    switch(extractorType)
    {
    //case SIFT:
    //    name = name + "SIFT";
    //    break;
    //case SURF:
    //    name = name + "SURF";
    //    break;
    case ORB:
        de = ORB::create();
        break;
    //case BRIEF:
    //    name = name + "BRIEF";
    //    break;
    case BRISK:
        de = BRISK::create();
        break;
    //case FREAK:
    //    name = name + "FREAK";
    //    break;
    case AKAZE:
        de = AKAZE::create();
        break;
    default: //**this is line 374**
        CV_Error( Error::StsBadArg, "Specified descriptor extractor type is not supported." );
        break;
    }

    return new javaDescriptorExtractor(de);
```

So the error clearly comes up, because case BRIEF is commented. So I modified it like that:

```
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
```

.
.
.

```
case BRIEF:
    de = xfeatures2d::BriefDescriptorExtractor::create();
    break;
```

.
.
.

```
default:
            CV_Error( Error::StsBadArg, "---TEST--- Specified descriptor extractor type is not supported." );
            break;
        }
```

After rebuiling in a fresh directory and using the new build, the exact same error is persistent. Not even "---TEST---" is included with the message.

So I am wondering why my changes do not have any effect.

I am also wondering why the file path is:

> /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp

This dirctory doesn't even exist on my system and googling it showed, that /home/maksim/ is part of a lot of different error messages on android.

The actual path before building is:

> C:\Users\JJG-CD\Desktop\Build_Workspace\opencv-3.1.0\modules\features2d\misc\java\src\cpp\features2d_manual.hpp

I hope somebody can explain to me what the problem is and eventually give me a hint how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up already but found the solution by chance. The reason my own built libraries have not been used was the fact that those libraries are usually provided by the opencv manager app. To get rid of OpenCV manager and use my own libraries I just needed to initialize OpenCV statically.

```
static {
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    // Handle initialization error}
}
```

Further details can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing almost certainly comes from a library that you link to that uses the same header file. When you recompile your code having changed the header, that header change only takes effect for the code you're actually compiling, and not the code that is already compiled in the libraries that you're also linking.

Look at your compile line and consider all the `-l` options as possible suspects.

This also explains the non-existent directory reference: this directory existed and was used at the time the library(ies) themselves were compiled on whatever machine they were compiled on.

If you want your header change to take effect in library code, the library itself needs to be recompiled. Have a look at your project configuration files: you may very well already have `make` or `cmake` options to do this.

Comment: Thanks for answering Smeeheey. I'd like to give you a 1up, but i don't have enough reputation (maybe somebody else could do it for me) Your comments shed some light on my issue. I'm compiling on win7 and cmake-gui, but I still might have found the option that could solve it. Apart from some options, that I knew exactly I needed changed I've been compiling with the default settings - one of them:  ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS = true. So I set it to false and give it another try. I'll updateas soon as i got a result.

Comment: ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS = false didn't help - still the same problem. Other than that I have no idea what else to change. Seems like it's a bug, that has already been reported a year ago: [link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5030) . Beeing a novice programmer, I think I have to give up on this

Comment: Why don't you share your exact compile line? If you're using make or cmake, please share the relevant makefile

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what file is the relevant makefile, as there is a whole bunch of them sved in my build directory. But i think what you are asking for is a summary of the configuration created by the selected options - so i guess this is what comes closest: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzvopkpwdzq4jff/configuration%20summary.txt?dl=0)